# Clock.schedule_interval doesn't schedule callback

Tags: kivy, python-3.4

I am testing the functionality of the kivy.clock.Clock.schedule_interval function.

My schedule_interval isn't calling the test function but rather exits without any errors.

What is it that I'm not understanding? I have correctly modeled this test by the documentation.

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

class TestClass:

    def __init__(self):
        print("function __init__.")
        schedule = Clock.schedule_interval(self.test, 1)

    def test(self, dt):
        print("function test.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = TestClass()
```

The expected output should be:

```
function __init__.
function test.
function test.
function test.
function test.
function test.
function test.
```

Instead I'm just getting:

```
function __init__.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that your program exits before one second passes. I'm not sure but I also assume that there has to be a kivy app in order for the Clock to work (I tried to make an empty while loop instead of running an app but that didn't help).

Here's an easy fix that gives the desired output:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.base import runTouchApp


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print("function __init__.")
        schedule = Clock.schedule_interval(self.test, 1)

    def test(self, dt):
        print("function test.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = TestClass()
    runTouchApp() # run an empty app so the program doesn't close
```

Otherwise consider making `TestClass` inherit from kivy's `App` and running it with `TestClass().run()` - you will achieve the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. It works both ways.